# Koch's postulates for judging if HIV causes AIDS

Tags: medical-science, hiv-aids

One of the most prominent proponents of the claim that HIV is not the cause of AIDS, [Peter Duesberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duesberg) claims in a [PNAS article from 1989](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC286556/?tool=pmcentrez) the following

> The hypothesis that HIV causes AIDS is
>   examined in terms of Koch's postulates
>   and epidemiological, biochemical,
>   genetic, and evolutionary conditions
>   of viral pathology. HIV does not
>   fulfill Koch's postulates

Koch's postulates are the follwing according to Wikipedia:

> 1. The microorganism must be found in abundance in all organisms suffering from the disease, but should not be found in healthy
>      organisms.
> 2. The microorganism must be isolated from a diseased organism and grown in pure culture.
> 3. The cultured microorganism should cause disease when introduced into a healthy organism.
> 4. The microorganism must be reisolated from the inoculated, diseased experimental host and identified as being identical to the original
>      specific causative agent.

Are Koch's postulates, formulated in the late 19th century, a valid principle for evaluating if HIV causes AIDS?

Comment: There is an updated version for the 21st century in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch%27s_postulates#Koch.E2.80.99s_postulates_for_the_21st_century

Comment: Does a virus even qualify as a micro-organism?  They can't reproduce without molesting a cell's genetic makeup, they don't have any metabolism, they can't move under their own power, they don't grow, etc etc etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tellingly, Koch himself eventually abandoned the strict postulates!

Other than that, there are heaps of known virus infections that are exceptions to the postulates. I wouldn't pay that much regard, and it is my understanding that nobody does.

Although I don't think failure to fulfil the postulates proves anything, it turns out there's actually [still some debate as to whether or not the HIV->AIDS causation does](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0952791596800756). I'm afraid I can't read the full article, but clue is in the title :)

Comment: That article is an editorial claiming that the accumulated evidence now shows that the HIV -> AIDS connection now fulfills Koch's postulates. They're cheating a tiny bit as they use documented cases for the requirement that HIV introduced into healthy individuals should cause AIDS, instead of doing a study infecting healthy persons with HIV. That kind of experiment would obviously be highly unethical.

Comment: Thanks for that input, @Fabian! And yes, it would be :) Regardless, I find that to be of less value than the fact that there are many known virus infections that do not fulfil all postulates. It seems commonly accepted that this is not a prerequisite to infer causation.

Comment: @Fabian: They can infect non-human primates with SIV.

Comment: Yea. THey can infect non human primates with SIV. Have this been done.

Comment: Could you post examples of virus infections that are exceptions to the postulates?

Answer (score 10):

Just from reading the [Wikipedia page of Koch's Postulates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch%27s_postulates), several flaws in them are immediately identified.

The first postulate ignores asymptomatic carriers, which Koch himself acknowledged. So an argument that some people have HIV but not AIDS shouldn't discount the HIV->AIDS causation.

The second postulate assumes that microorganisms can be grown in a culture. I'm no microbiologist, but I don't believe this is true of viruses - they need to be in living cells to reproduce.

The third and fourth postulates require infecting a healthy host, which is unethical in  terminal diseases that affect humans and not lab animals.

Comment: Viruses are also cultivated in bacteria.

Comment: @user8150 - Yes, but that can only be done with virus that infect bacteria.